# add a wildcard to a JavaScript switch statement

Tags: javascript

is there a way i can create a switch statement with a wildcard with the logic of:

```
case: '/jobs/'+WILDCARD and ending in +'-jobs' :
```

this is for the window.location.pathname, which could be '/jobs/design-jobs', or '/jobs/engineer-jobs' etc

but, there are other pages which start with '/jobs' I don't want this to apply to, e.g '/jobs/post'

or any suggestions on a better way?

Comment: Nope, afaik this can only be done with regex. And a `case:` label must be a literal value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick you can use in some cases could be to use a function to normalize the input of your switch, to turn variable inputs into the specific cases:

Instead of:

```
switch(input) {
  case 'something': // something
  case 'otherthing': // another
  case '/jobs/'+WILDCARD: // special
}
```

You could do:

```
function transformInput (input) {
  if (input.match(/jobs.*-jobs/) return 'JOBS';
  return input;
}

switch(transformInput(input)) {
  case 'something': // something
  case 'otherthing': // another
  case 'JOBS': // special
}
```

Comment: Thanks! used like: var curPage = window.location.pathname.match(/jobs.*-jobs/) ? 'search-results' : window.location.pathname; switch(curPage){}

Answer (score 1):

No there are not wildcards for `switch` statements, but you could e.g. use `RegExp` and test against it:

```
if( path.match(/^\/jobs\/(.*)-jobs$/) !== null ) {
    //jobs url
} else {
    switch( path ) {
        case '/jobs/post':
           //something else
           break; 
    } 

}
```

Comment: Or you can abstract that via function

Comment: @djay Sure, thats to the OP how do do it so that it is fits into his code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var categories = {
    design: function(){ console.log('design'); },
    engineer: function(){ console.log('engineer'); }
};

for(var category in categories)
    if(window.location.pathname === '/jobs/' + category + '-jobs')
        categories[category]();
```